# How to add conditional column for kendo ui grid using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can we add a conditional column to the kendo ui grid .

I am having JSON input like this

```
    [{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    "Supplier": {
        "SupplierID": 1,
        "SupplierName": "Exotic Liquids"
    },
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages"
    },
    "UnitPrice": 18.0,
    "UnitsInStock": 39,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "layers": [
      {
         "layer_Layer1": {
            "layerType": "top",
            "layer": "L1",
            "groups": []
         }
      }  ]
},{
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "Supplier": {
        "SupplierID": 1,
        "SupplierName": "Exotic Liquids"
    },
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages"
    },
    "UnitPrice": 19.0,
    "UnitsInStock": 17,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "layers": [
      {
         "layer_Layer2": {
            "layerType": "top",
            "layer": "L2",
            "groups": []
         }
      }
   ]
}]
```

Here in `columns.fields` I am giving `layers[0].layer_Layer1.layer` but sometimes I get `layers[0].layer_Layer2.layer`.

How can we configure this in kendo ui ?

Plunker : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXLY7c?p=preview)

Comment: It depends on the fields provided to kendo grid so you can make it but adding or rebinding your grid column definition by putting some conditions

Comment: Where to put conditions, Is it possible to hide if field is undefined ?

Comment: while creating columns array

Comment: I have added Plunker . Can you give me updated one ?

Comment: It will not show you data because you can get all properties of you data object so from that you can define columns

Comment: Didn't get last comment :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94188/discussion-between-bpbhat77-and-jayant-patil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you want to display in a column the value of either `layer_Layer1` or `layer_Layer2`, depending on which one is blank or not.

You can try a [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) for that:

```
# if (layers && layers[0].layer_Layer1) { # 
    #: layers[0].layer_Layer1.layer # 
# } else if (layers && layers[0].layer_Layer2) { #
    #: layers[0].layer_Layer2.layer # 
# } #
```

[Updated demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ev47Bu38DrzMNzI7F8Wi?p=preview) [Another version](http://dojo.telerik.com/eFEfO).